# Django Feed error: 'function' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django, feed

I am working with Django 1.8, and am attempting to create a simple feed for my project.   Here is the feeds.py file which creates the feed:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatewords
from valueFact.models import ValueFactPost


class LatestPostsFeed(Feed):
    title = "Contributions from members"
    link = "/companies/"
    description = "New Contributions by members"

    def items(self):
        return ValueFactPost.published.all()[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return truncatewords(item.body, 30)
```

My app url.py file is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from valueFact import views
from valueFact.feeds import LatestPostsFeed


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        views.valueFactListView.as_view(),
        name='valueFact_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.valuefact_detail,
        name='valuefact_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<fact_id>\d+)/share/$',
        views.valuefact_share,
        name='valuefact_share'),
    url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostsFeed(), name='post_feed'),
]
```

I direct the browser to the url 'companies/feed', and get the following error.  Note, that I already included all of this applications url in the main projects url conf file, and it works normally ( e.g, I get the page I want when I type 127.0.0.1:8000/companies)

Edit:  here is the full trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/feed/

Django Version: 1.8 Python Version: 3.5.0 Installed Applications: ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.sites',  'django.contrib.sitemaps',  'djangobower',  'rest_framework',  'stockData',  'accounts',  'functional_tests',  'valueFact') Installed Middleware: ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback: File "/Users/djunh/Programming/viex/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/djunh/Programming/viex/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py" in __call__
  43.         feedgen = self.get_feed(obj, request) File "/Users/djunh/Programming/viex/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py" in get_feed
  174.                 request.is_secure(), File "/Users/djunh/Programming/viex/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py" in add_domain
  19.     if url.startswith('//'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /companies/feed/ Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: What is `item.body` function? It looks like you wanted to use `item.body()` or something like this? Or perhaps it was supposed to be a property but you've forgotten `@property`? That's the only thing that can be deducted from the snippet you've shown us.

Comment: item.body is the body text of the post model I created ( called ValueFactPost).  In addition, the model has a title.  However, these are working correctly on my application and I am able to access them without a problem.  Figured less is more and excluded the model from the post..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define a `get_absolute_url(self)` on your model you might need to define an `item_link`

```
# item_link is only needed if NewsItem has no get_absolute_url method.
def item_link(self, item):
    return reverse('news-item', args=[item.pk])
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/syndication/#a-simple-example):

> To specify the contents of `<link>`, you have two options. For each item
>   in **items()**, Django first tries calling the **item_link()** method on the
>   **Feed** class. In a similar way to the title and description, it is
>   passed it a single parameter, **item**. If that method doesn’t exist,
>   Django tries executing a **get_absolute_url()** method on that object.
>   Both **get_absolute_url()** and **item_link()** should return the item’s URL
>   as a normal Python string. As with **get_absolute_url()**, the result of
>   **item_link()** will be included directly in the URL, so you are
>   responsible for doing all necessary URL quoting and conversion to
>   ASCII inside the method itself.